# SSRS 2012 - Rows being suppressed on web report

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

we've being busy upgrading our server from SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2012 and are facing an unusual bug in SSRS 2012 that consists in some rows simply not being shown on html view, but same rows being shown correctly on any export format.

[Fig.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuakt.png) shows a fragment of a broken html report, where I glued together the bottom and the top of two pages.

[Fig.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0qY3.png) shows the exact same area, exported to a pdf document. Highlighted are the rows that should be in html mode.

Curiously, the rows are exactly in that transitional area between pages so maybe that's a clue.

Anybody any thoughts or ways to fix it? We've even come to the extent of applying 2012'SP3 to our servers on hopes of it being corrected, but no luck...

Answer (score 0):

Well, seems that the answer was below our noses the whole time...

Never forget to properly set the report's `Page Size` and `Interactive Size` properties, our case was the `Interactive Size` being bigger than `Page Size`, making records 'appear' in the web report but not being properly shown.